# How to mock a variable value in a ng-container in angular jest test

Tags: angular, testing, ts-jest

I have a question about how to mock a variable value in a ng-container in angular jest test.

my html looks like this:

```
<ng-container *ngVar="testFacade.getData as data">
</ng-container>
```

now I want to test this component html,

but the question is how can I mock in this case "data"?

any idea?

Comment: Unless I'm missing somehting, I think you just want to mock `testFacade.getData` and `data` will receive that value.